# Keeping weight matrix constant in TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

So I am writing a word2vec model in TensorFlow following Andre Ng's design influenced by Bengio's paper. In this model the word embeddings are the input and the gradient descent is continued upto the input layer assuming there is a previous layer.

I have gone around this problem by implementing a one-hot model for words which will activate certain nodes (corresponding to the  word in the next layer) only by choosing a identity weight matrix. The only problem is that this weight matrix needs to remain constant. How can that be done in TensorFlow?

**TL;DR** - A weight matrix for a certain layer of NN needs to be kept constant (also this is layer is the last layer in back-propagation), how can this be achieved in TensorFlow?

Comment: What about `trainable=False` keyword upon instantiation?

Comment: @a_guest i am new to tensorflow...so if you think it works, you can write an answer, and if it works..i'll accept and upvote 2mrw for sure

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want to achieve. Maybe you could add a short snippet that explains your architecture better and what you exactly want to achieve. From my impression you simply want to do something like `tf.layers.dense(..., trainable=False)`. But again, I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: @a_guest you are correct, i found a similar answer...the real thing i wanted to achieve was train the input as well by assuming there was a layer before it, since i dont know how to do that, i decided to encode the input as weights and train them